# Object is undefined or null

Tags: object, next.js

Please help me in solving this error.
[This is the error coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz3Wf.png)

Comment: Aryan, please share the code in detail and explain what you want to achieve in detail. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.